# Google API: How to get Birthday and Location?

Tags: google-api

It is very strange, when I try to get the birthday from Google API after a successful OAUTH2.0 authentication,

```
dob = response.get('birthday')
```

I get a strange value:

```
'0000-09-07'
```

day and month seems correct, but why is the year 0000?

And how do I get the location? Is there an API specification that lists all the possible lookup values one can request?

Answer (score 1):

The user has most-likely hid its birth year, it is an option on Google+.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the user provided only the month and day of their birth, but not the year.  But what API are you calling?  The [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#gcBirthday) shows that type of response as `--09-07` instead of the value `0000-09-07` that you are showing.